# Vectorising Multiple Wilcoxon tests in R

Tags: r, statistics

*Apologies for the inelegance of this question, and of the example.  I'm a medical doctor who's pretty out of his depth coding in R, but am trying to get better*

I need to perform multiple Wilcoxon tests on a dataset in R.  (*I know about the perils of multiple comparisons; in fact this is used to follow on from a set of LME analyses in order to establish confidence intervals using the Hodges-Lehman estimate*).

My data comprises a number of variables, measured at multiple time points in multiple subjects.  I'd like to have a way of comparing different timepoints, creating a new 'htest' object for each comparison.

Here is an MWE approximation of my data frame structure:

```
example.data <- data.frame(
                matrix(data=c(
                'A',0,0,24,0,
                'A',1,1,20,-1,
                'A',2,2,18,-1.4,
                'A',3,0.5,21,-0.6,
                'B',0,0,22,0,
                'B',1,1.2,19,-2.2,
                'B',2,1.8,20,-3,
                'B',3,0.3,21,-1,
                'C',0,0,24,0,
                'C',1,0.8,22,0.1,
                'C',2,2.2,16,-0.6,
                'C',3,1,23,-0.2,
                'D',0,0,33,0,
                'D',1,6,31,-0.4,
                'D',2,6.3,27,-0.3,
                'D',3,2.2,31,-0.1),
                nrow=16,byrow=T))
colnames(example.data) <- c('Subject','Timepoint','Variable1','Variable2','Variable3')
example.data$Timepoint = factor(example.data$Timepoint,levels=c(0,1,2,3))
example.data[,3:5] = sapply(example.data[,3:5],as.numeric)
```

The best way I can come up with is with a pretty ugly for loop, which looks like this:

```
## Step 2 - Multiple Wilcoxons

variablenames <- names(example.data)[-c(1,2)]

for (obj in variablenames[3:5]){
    obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint1 <- toString(paste(obj,'.wilcoxon.Timepoint1',sep='')) # create 100percent object name
    obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint2 <- toString(paste(obj,'.wilcoxon.timepoint2',sep='')) # create 100percent object name
    obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint3 <- toString(paste(obj,'.wilcoxon.timepoint3',sep='')) # create 100percent object name
        assign(eval(obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint1),wilcox.test(example.data[example.data$Timepoint==0,which(variablenames == obj)],example.data[example.data$Timepoint==1,which(variablenames == obj)],conf.int=T,paired=T))

        assign(eval(obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint2),wilcox.test(example.data[example.data$Timepoint==0,which(variablenames == obj)],example.data[example.data$Timepoint==2,which(variablenames == obj)],conf.int=T,paired=T))

        assign(eval(obj.wilcoxon.Timepoint3),wilcox.test(example.data[example.data$Timepoint==0,which(variablenames == obj)],example.data[example.data$Timepoint==3,which(variablenames == obj)],conf.int=T,paired=T))
}
```

I'm sure there's an elegant, vectorised way of doing this, but how do I?

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
example.data[,3:5] = sapply(example.data[,3:5],as.numeric)
```

should be

```
example.data[,3:5] = apply(example.data[,3:5],2,as.numeric)
```

The following should give your a more compact solution.

To start, load these two libraries. As suggested by Roland, `reshape2` transforms data to long format and `dplyr` is a faster version of `plyr`.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
```

Transform the data into desired format

```
baseline = melt(example.data %.% filter(Timepoint==0) %.% select(-Timepoint), 
        "Subject", value.name = "base")
comparison = melt(example.data %.% filter(Timepoint!=0), c("Subject", "Timepoint"))
join.data = left_join(comparison, baseline)
```

You can see what `join.data` look like:

```
> join.data
   Subject Timepoint  variable value base
1        A         1 Variable1   1.0    0
2        A         2 Variable1   2.0    0
3        A         3 Variable1   0.5    0
4        B         1 Variable1   1.2    0
5        B         2 Variable1   1.8    0
6        B         3 Variable1   0.3    0
7        C         1 Variable1   0.8    0
8        C         2 Variable1   2.2    0
9        C         3 Variable1   1.0    0
10       D         1 Variable1   6.0    0
11       D         2 Variable1   6.3    0
12       D         3 Variable1   2.2    0
13       A         1 Variable2  20.0   24
14       A         2 Variable2  18.0   24
15       A         3 Variable2  21.0   24
16       B         1 Variable2  19.0   22
17       B         2 Variable2  20.0   22
18       B         3 Variable2  21.0   22
19       C         1 Variable2  22.0   24
20       C         2 Variable2  16.0   24
21       C         3 Variable2  23.0   24
22       D         1 Variable2  31.0   33
23       D         2 Variable2  27.0   33
24       D         3 Variable2  31.0   33
25       A         1 Variable3  -1.0    0
26       A         2 Variable3  -1.4    0
27       A         3 Variable3  -0.6    0
28       B         1 Variable3  -2.2    0
29       B         2 Variable3  -3.0    0
30       B         3 Variable3  -1.0    0
31       C         1 Variable3   0.1    0
32       C         2 Variable3  -0.6    0
33       C         3 Variable3  -0.2    0
34       D         1 Variable3  -0.4    0
35       D         2 Variable3  -0.3    0
36       D         3 Variable3  -0.1    0
```

Finally, the main dish

```
res = join.data %.% group_by(variable) %.% do(
        function(df) {
                df %.% group_by(Timepoint) %.% do (
                    function(d) wilcox.test(d$base, d$value, conf.int=TRUE, paired=TRUE)
                    )
        })
```

`res` is a list of list: `res[[i]][[t]]` is the result for variable `i` at time point `t

For example, `res[[1]][[2]]` is the result for variable 1 at time point 2.

---

Alternatively, you can do the traditional `split`

```
res = lapply(split(join.data, join.data$variable),
    function(df){
        lapply(split(df, df$Timepoint), function(d){
           wilcox.test(d$base, d$value, conf.int= TRUE, paired=TRUE)
       })
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @'RandyLai'!  This does exactly what I'm looking for.  I think there may have been a problem with your join.data example - values for 'Variable' in rows 13-24 appear to have been multiplied by 3.  'dplyr' is a very useful package, although it is making me have to re-think the structure of my code significantly - it feels as though it makes R a completely different language.  I can see the advantage of using it, though.

Comment: I don't see the problem of multiplying by 3. But I think you can fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `wilcox.test` is not vectorized, you can't do this without loops. However, you can still do better than using `assign` and `eval`. This is more R-ish:

```
library(reshape2)
#long format is better:
example.data <- melt(example.data, id.vars=c("Subject", "Timepoint"))

library(plyr)
#split-apply-combine
res <- dlply(example.data, .(Subject), 
             function(df) lapply(unique(df[df$Timepoint!="0", "Timepoint"]),
                                 function(i, DF) {
                                   wilcox.test(DF[DF$Timepoint=="0", "value"],
                                               DF[DF$Timepoint==i, "value"],
                                               conf.int=FALSE, paired=TRUE)                                            
                                 }, DF=df))
```

Note that I set `conf.int=FALSE` to avoid an error from `wilcox.test` that is probably due to the limited data.

You can than access the second test for Subject B with:

```
res[["B"]][[2]]
```

Comment: I think you should melt and group the Variable1, 2 and 3. But not group the subjects.